# Converting a region code (short string up to 4 characters) to a 32-bit integer

Tags: c, casting

There is a function that converts region code strings (1 to 4 characters and null terminator) to 32 bit integers codes to be used in maps as keys or values.

Blindly casting char* to int* is bad as it can be less than 4 bytes including null terminator.

Currently the code is like this

```
uint32_t region_code_key(const char* region_code) {
  unsigned char buf[4] = "\0";
  strncpy(buf, region_code, 4);
  return *((int*)buf);
}
```

I believe that buf may be not well aligned causing problems on some platforms. Is it a valid concern?
The endianity is not a concern as such numbers are used only on local machines, only as keys.

It's a very simple function but If alignment concern is valid I see two ways to rewrite it.
Here we just convert it byte by byte

```
uint32_t region_code_key(const char* region_code) {
    unsigned char* region_code_iter;
    unsigned char* region_code_end = region_code+4;
    uint32_t code_as_int = 0;
    for (region_code_iter = region_code; region_code_iter!=region_code_end && (*region_code_iter); ++region_code_iter) {
        code_as_int = (code_as_int<<8) | (*region_code_iter);
    }
    return code_as_int;
}
```

Alternatively use union to ensure better alignment:

```
uint32_t region_code_key(const char* region_code) {
union {
                char[sizeof(uint32_t)] as_string;
                uint32_t as_int;
} region = {0, 0, 0, 0};
strncpy(region.as_string, region_code, sizeof (region_code));
return region.as_int;
}
```

Is alignment a valid concern? If so which alternative seems less ugly to you?

Answer (score 2):

Even if the `char` array is not aligned, your `*((uint32_t *)buf)` will be correct: the compiler will ensure the necessary operations are performed.

Note that I used `unit32_t`: the C standard does not guarantee the size of an `int`.

One thing: since these are 4 byte integers, you can use an endianness-independent way of doing things by using `htonl()`/`ntohl()`.

Comment: On some microprocessors, an unaligned access is not legal, even though you get away with it on x86.

Comment: For such microprocessors however, the compiler will do the right thing anyway, right? ;)

Comment: For a procedure with a single parameter, as shown here, the compiler/runtime would take care to align the stack frame, so the code would work. However, the compilers I’ve seen will **not** generate special code for the cast as such, they will assume the programmer knew `buf` was aligned properly, and if it was not, the program will crash.

Comment: On some systems the cast `*((uint32_t *)buf)` when buf is not properly aligned will lead to a crash

Answer (score 2):

The `buf` array is on the stack. The compiler is not going to put misaligned variables on the stack.  The stack frame created on a function call will put CPU registers on the stack, so if your processor has 32-bit registers (or greater), your first solution is okay for uint32_t alignment.

Note that the size in the 3rd solution `strcpy` is wrong:

```
strncpy(region.as_string, region_code, sizeof (region_code));
```

should be

```
strncpy(region.as_string, region_code, sizeof region);
```

For what it is worth, here is another solution :-)

```
static uint32_t region_code_key(const char *region_code)
{
    const uint32_t mask[] = {0, 0xff, 0xffff, 0xffffff, 0xffffffff};
    size_t len = strlen(region_code);
    if (len > 4) {
        len = 4;
    }
    const uint32_t code =
        (uint32_t)region_code[0]       |
        (uint32_t)region_code[1] << 8  |
        (uint32_t)region_code[2] << 16 |
        (uint32_t)region_code[3] << 24;
    return code & mask[len];
}
```